# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver

Tags: jdbc, kotlin

Java can't find the jdbc driver when I run a program like:

java -cp ojdbc14.jar;. -jar TestDB.jar

I have tried fiddling with the classpath, but java doesn't seem to check the classpath when running an app bundled in a jar file.

```
// code compiles but produces a Classnotfound exception at runtime

import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.ResultSet
import java.sql.SQLException
import java.sql.Statement

import oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver


fun main(args:Array<String>){
    println("make a start")
    DriverManager.registerDriver( OracleDriver())
    // val conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost", "***", "*****");


}
```

Comment: Is this “app bundled in a jar file” a simple executable jar, or is it a ‘fat’ jar or war with its own bootstrap, classloader, etc.?

Comment: the jar was created with kotlinc -include-runtime testDB.kt -d TestDB.jar

Comment: ojdbc14 is pretty old (and for Java 1.4), you may want to consider trying a newer version.